# Converter campo do banco de dados divido em vírgulas em variáveis separadas com PHP

Tags: php

Como posso converter resultados do banco de dados que estão dentro de um campo dividido por vírgulas, em varáveis separadas independente do número de resultados contidos no campo.

Exemplo:

Tenho:

```
$row['campo'] = 333,444,555,6666
```

Preciso:

```
$var1='333'; 
$var2='444'; 

.
.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usando a função [explode()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php);

Ex:

```
$row['campo'] = 333,444,555,6666

$aux = explode(",", $row['campo']);

foreach($aux as $v){
  echo $v;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, perfeito Fernando.